# How can I make matplotlib mark_inset display line on top of the graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code

```
ax = plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(time_list, data[1], color='red')
plt.plot(time_list, y_offset, color='blue')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black')
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black')

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 4.5, loc=4)
axins.plot(time_list, data[1], color='red')
axins.plot(time_list, y_offset, color='blue')
axins.axvline(x=0, color='black')
axins.axhline(y=0, color='black')
axins.axis([2, 3, -0.01, 0.01])
plt.yticks(visible=False)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=3, loc2=1, fc="none", ec="0.0")
```

which plot the graph like this

[image]

as you can see the zoom box line is behind the red plot but the link line is on top of the plot so how can I make the zoom box line become on top of the plot?

Comment: Have you tried calling `zoomed_inset_axes` after all of your `plot` calls?

Comment: @farenorth I move the code to show the zoom axes all the way down to before calling plt.show() --> same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cause the box to appear on top of the graphed line by using [Z-order](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html). Artists with higher Z-order are plotted on top of artists with lower Z-order. The default for lines is 2, so add `zorder = 3` to `mark_inset`.

Full code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes, mark_inset
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
time_list = np.linspace(0, 7, 1000)
data = np.random.random(1000) - .5
plt.plot(time_list, data, color='red')

plt.axvline(x=0, color='black')
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black')

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 4.5, loc=4)
axins.plot(time_list, data, color='red')
axins.axvline(x=0, color='black')
axins.axhline(y=0, color='black')
axins.axis([2, 3, -0.01, 0.01])
plt.yticks(visible=False)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=3, loc2=1, fc="none", ec="0.0", zorder = 3)
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with mark_inset box above plotted line]